# change vscode Code Analysis Mode for C

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Simple question but one I cannot find the answer to - having scoured the settings I can't find how to change my Code Analysis Mode from Manual. I presume other modes must exist since it bothers to tell me which mode it's in. I'm learning C so this feature is new to me.

[image: Code Analysis Mode img]

Comment: Silly question since I can’t tell from my research. What language is your project written in?

Comment: Which kind of Code Analysis Mode are you referring to?

Comment: It's written in C. The Code Analysis Mode I'm referring to is Manual.